# What do you call an online newspaper?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Is there a better word for a news website besides "aggregator" (which implies the source only curates information) or "blog" (which implies the source only does opinion/commentary/no real reporting and also implies there is only one contributor)?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use ***online newspaper***?

Comment: No. But if a website does not have a print newspaper, "online newspaper" seems outdated to me.

Comment: You could look at new words like **e-zine** (which is perhaps more of an online magazine than a newspaper).

Comment: @Kyle But we still *dial* telephone numbers, after hearing a *dialling tone*. And we still tune in to radio and TV stations. Indeed there are scores of these things - ships still *sail* the oceans, even super-tankers of  500,000 tonnes. So why not an online *newspaper*?

Comment: It's all over the map.

Comment: Good point, @WS2. Is "online newspaper" still the most accepted term for a news website without a print newspaper, then?

Comment: @Kyle I would have thought so, though in my own case I usually refer to the newspaper by name e.g. *The Guardian - online edition*.

Comment: @WS2 -- _The Guardian_ is not a good example here, since it _is_ an actual newspaper. If someone asked you, "What is _The Daily Beast_?" (for example) what would you say?

Comment: @Kyle I'd say *A newspaper only available online*. The point surely is that things like *The Daily Beast* and *The Huffington Post* include in their names elements which associate them with traditional newspapers - *daily*, *post*. It must therefore be their proprietors' wishes to have them regarded as newspapers. So why not call them that?

Comment: @WS2 You are right. Newspapers it is. After all, _journalists_ no longer write in paper journals, and the word remains.

Comment: @Kyle Nor, indeed, do people any longer *write* - they type at a keyboard. Before long everything will be done by speech and voice recognition - if it isn't at present. But presumably we will still be speaking of journalists and authors as *writers*.

Comment: @WS2 Ah, keen observation with _write_. Very true.

Answer (score 1):

**e-paper** or **electronic (news) paper** is a valid term when referring to websites owned by Publication Agencies/Newspapers

For example, take a look at these news websites from two popular dailies in India.

- [The Hindu](https://epaper.thehindu.com/index.php?rt=login/loginAction)
- [The Times of India](http://epaperbeta.timesofindia.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Not a word, but there is a phrase that is better than "aggregator" or "blog". You've even used it in your question, and it's not "online newspaper"; it's "news website"!

We have **newspapers**, which are **news** on **paper**. We also have **news websites**, which are **news** on a **website**.

The equivalence seems sensible to me.

[That said, [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=news%20website%2Conline%20newspaper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnews%20website%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conline%20newspaper%3B%2Cc0) would suggest that the world doesn't agree with me, as "online newspaper" is far more popular a phrase than "news website".]